# ggplot2::stat_density_2d : no method for function ‘size’ for signature ‘"numeric"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

These are my loaded packages:

```
   library(sf)
   library(colorspace)
   library(ggspatial)
   library(dismo)
   library(ggmap)
   library(basemaps)
   library(rlang)
   library(dplyr)
   library(ggplot2)
```

This is my code:

```
   myLocation <- "South America"
   myMap <- get_map(location = myLocation, zoom = 4, source= "google",
             maptype= "satellite")
   ggmap(myMap)
   TestData <- read.csv("TestData.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", col.names = TRUE)
   newsa <- TestData[ ,2:4]
   ggmap(myMap, extent = "device") +
   stat_density_2d(data = newsa, aes(x=DLongitude, y=DLatitude))
              size(0.01,bins = 16, geom = "polygon") +
                scale_filled_gradient("red") +
                scale_alpha(range = c(0,0.3), guide = FALSE)
```

Was expecting a heat map without contours

Comment: Please remove all the packages that are not strictly necessary to produce the error. Also please edit your question to make it reproducible. We do not have TestData, so create something similar with R code.

Comment: I think `size` should be inside the `stat_density` call, otherwise, add a plus sign at the end of the `stat_density` line